# How to use validate in vue

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I used validate directive in my form to validate content.

```
<input type="text" v-model="address" name="address" ref="address" v-validate="{ regex:/^([0-9]+|[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2}?)$/ }" data-vv-validate-on="blur">
```

But it returns the error like below:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: validate
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you included `Vue.use(VeeValidate);` after importing `vee-validate`?

Comment: To use v-validate, should I have to import VeeValidate? Or what? Please teach me.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/getting-started.html#usage):

We can use the `VeeValidate` plugin using the [`Vue.use()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin) global method either like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

or include the script directly like:

```
<script src="path/to/vue.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.use(VeeValidate); // good to go.
</script>
```

**Demo:**

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    address: ''
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@<3.0.0"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <span>Enter some text, then remove focus from textbox to validate</span><br/>
    <input type="text" v-model="address" name="address" ref="address" v-validate="{ regex:/^([0-9]+|[0-9]+,[0-9]{0,2}?)$/ }" data-vv-validate-on="blur">
    
    <br/>
    <span>{{ errors.first('address') }}</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work for me.
For reference I am developing nuxt2.0.0.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqxk0lw813) to show the issue happening.

Comment: after edit, you need to save the changes first, then a new link will be generated. paste that link here.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-franklin-tm7cb?file=/nuxt.config.js

Comment: You will need to add the `vee-validate` like [this](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#vue-plugins) Also, in index.vue you are using `v-model="address"` but you have not declared any data for it.. add data also like `data: {
    address: ''
  },`